# Selbig vs Selbe

Tags: adjective

What is the difference between *selbig* und *selbe*? For example for the following case:

> X ist der alte Name desselben Produktes.
>
> X ist der alte Name desselbigen Produktes.

Comment: I corrected two spelling mistakes: "desselbe" and "desselbingen" are both written as one one. See here: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/derselbe and http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/derselbige

Comment: Desselbingen Bingen wie Bingen am Rhein?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no that big differences.

1. Both words are used to describe something that has been called already.

Ich habe gelbe Schuhe. Klara trug *dieselben* gestern. -> I have yellow shoes. Klara wore *the same* (shoes) yesterday.

Ich habe gelbe Schuhe. Klara trug *dieselbigen* gestern. -> I have yellow shoes. Klara wore *the same* (shoes) yesterday.

2. Or if something happens at the same time:

Ich gehe zur Schule. Kai geht zur *selben* Stunde zur Schule. -> I'm going to school. Kai is going to school at *the same* (hour).

... Kai geht zur *selbigen* Stunde zur Schule. -> has the same meaning.

__

I could make many more examples but the word selbe and selbig **got the same meaning in *the most cases***.

**But you have to know that nobody use selbig anymore.** Except some very smart guys or a editorial team at least. ^^

Comment: Google-News: Tagesspiegel-vor 5 Stunden, "... den Allgäuer Alpen, hat er selbige schon um die 40 Mal Richtung Neuschwanstein überquert,..."

Answer (score 2):

Eigentlich war "selbig" *der-/die/dasselbe* substantiviert.

> -Das Buch ist von Günter Grass.
>   °Ist das nicht der Autor der "Blechtrommel"?
>   -Der Selbige. (nowadays: derselbige/derselbe)

Inzwischen werden beide Wörter synonym gebraucht.

Comment: 'Derselbige' schreibt man zusammen (siehe Links zu Duden oben in meinem Kommentar)